# Oracle SQL Partition By to Select the Most Recent Date

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using the below SQL to select the top of stack most recent life event from my `employee_life_events` table.  In order to pull top of stack (most recent) I needed to pull the highest `le_seq_no` for each `life_event_date` by `ssn`.  So with the SQL below I have the top of stack life event record for each member (ssn) by date.  I now need to pull the most recent date.  Now I know that I could try to build another sub query and use a max function (not sure exactly how so tips on that would be appreciated), but I am also wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this with the partition by statement.  By either adding a field to the `partition by` portion or by  adding a field to the `order by` portion.

So to sum it all up, I need to pull the top of stack (most recent life event record) from the `employee_life_events` table by SSN.  The most top of stack life event record is the record (per SSN) that is the most recent `life_event_date`, and has the highest `le_seq_no` (for that particular date).

```
SELECT *
FROM

(SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT ele1.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ele1.SSN, LIFE_EVENT_DATE ORDER BY LIFE_EVENT_DATE DESC, LE_SEQ_NO DESC) as seqnum
    FROM EMPLOYEE_LIFE_EVENTS ele1) ele1
WHERE seqnum = 1) ele
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The most top of stack life event record is the record (per SSN) that is the most recent life_event_date, and has the highest le_seq_no (for that particular date).

I think that you want:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        e.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by ssn
            order by life_event_date desc, le_seq_no desc
        ) rn
    from employee_life_events e
) t
where rn = 1
```

This uses a different partition and sort than your original query. I also eliminated an unnecessary level of nesting.